# How to install ownCloud on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, owncloud

We have a huge server with Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and 12Tb of storage. We want to use some of that amount of space to install a program like ownCloud/Dropbox there.

I've started with ownCloud but I got a lot of problems and getting 403 errors. 
[error windows server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOBas.jpg)

PHP is not working properly so I can't go to the installing ownCloud page. Is there any tutorial or alternative solution to use a Windows Server as Dropbox/ownCloud?

Thanks!

Comment: So, do you want to install Owncloud in windows or do you want a alternative to it? I am confused

Comment: Did you install all the requirements for ownCloud? It needs PHP and MySQL/MariaDB, also the correct server setup. Maybe you should switch to XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: @Orphans for now, a solution or help to install properly ownCloud on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: @Broco even if I install using XAMPP, I get an error: 'Error: Cannot create file "C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini. Access denied'

Comment: @RobertoMeijide Owncloud is not supported anymore in the Windows plattform.https://owncloud.org/blog/owncloud-server-8-1-will-not-support-windows-as-server-platform-natively/

Comment: @Orphans any alternative for Windows Servers? :(

Comment: @RobertoMeijide Propably SyncThing, btsync.. Closet as you get

Comment: Roberto, the specific error you are getting in the screenshot is 401 permission denied. It is attempting to list the contents of the owncloud/ directory. You need to set a Default Document. This will resolve that specific error, whether OC will actually work in IIS or not... I have no idea.

Comment: @DylanKnoll I did your solution of setting a Default Document and now is resolving right, but displays a HTTP 500 error.